# Let my javascript function be displayed in fullscreen on ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad, resize

i wrote a javascript game that can be played in the browser. When im playing it on an ipad, it is too big, and you have to scroll to see everything.

How can i adjust it to be always as big as the screen size of the ipad if it is played on it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width, height=device-height, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

More reading here:
[meta "viewport" device-width: Wrong width small on Opera Mobile 9.7 (10 works)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974703/meta-viewport-device-width-wrong-width-small-on-opera-mobile-9-7-10-works)

From here on you have to calculate with screen.width and height values to properly scale, but with the previous meta you'll atleast have a consistent value regarding screen dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup this `<meta>` tag in your html head section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

If that is not enough, use `css media queries` to further customize your elements for mobile devices, like

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  /* Style adjustments for viewports 480px and over */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Style adjustments for viewports 768px and over */
}
```